# How to read this LASSO Coefficient Path Plot?

Tags: machine-learning, lasso, regularization, linear, glmnet

I am seeing this plot [(side 5) here](http://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/TALKS/glmnet.pdf) a lot in machine learning literature. But how to read it? In general I know $\lambda$ is increasing from left to right, and we are getting larger coefficients. But

What are the x and y axis? and two scales of each axis?

[image]

Comment: The labels on this plot's axes are quite clear about what it is showing.  They are both unitless quantities.  What kind of explanation are you looking for, then?

Comment: Going further, if you look at p.68-70 of ESL, lasso is explained and on p.70 a very similar diagram is created with more information.